# Upload Zip file on github and extract once uploaded

Tags: github, zip

I am importing my project in github, due to its large size, its taking long. So I compressed my project and uploaded it on github.

Is there any way to extract it on github itself? I cant see anything in its UI but is there any command or script available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem, unfortunately, there isn't (to the best of my knowledge.). I was able to upload a large file to Github by using the git large file storage. (https://git-lfs.github.com/)

If you use Linux, here is the instruction:

quick install git-lfs (https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install)

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

install the Git command line extension.

```
git lfs install
```

Select the extension of the large file types you'd like Git LFS to manage. For me, it was a ".pb " file from retraining the inception-v3 model.

```
git lfs track "*.pb"  #  change "pb" to the extension of your large file.
```

Make sure .gitattributes is tracked

```
git add .gitattributes
```

Finally, just commit and push to GitHub as you normally would.

```
git add retrain.pb  #  change "retrain.pb" to the name of your large file.
git commit -m "First commit"
git push origin master
```

Or you could just include all your files in the project dir.

```
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GIT's features for that, do not upload as you used to like by FTP. GIT is what helps you tracking changes automatically, and you don't need to worry about that anymore. Above that it has tons of useful options

Comment: Is there any way to upload zip file and extract using GIT command ?

Comment: no you cant extract it using GIT command when it is uploaded.